# ¿como hacer una consulta en firebase con indice compuesto?

Tags: firebase, reactjs, redux

Estoy tratando de hacer una consulta en firebase, pero cuando reviso los datos me bota un erro el cual me dice que es necesario tener un index(indice) para poder proseguir con la consulta, este es el error que me bota en el navegador:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el codigo que estoy implementando:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el incice compuesto que he reado en el link que venia en el error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Que estoy haciendo mal para que apecar de estar haciendo el indice me bote el error?

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so] por favor evita poner imagenes e incluir el codigo, para que tu prregunta sea mejor recibida por la comunidad, las imgenes no se pueden copiar en un IDE para ejecutar el codigo. Igualmente , no borres parte del error, o almenos indica a que se refiere si lo haces, una ruta, tabla ..

Comment: Encontré el error, al pareces es necesario tener el mismo orden de uso en el indice compuesto que en el código

Comment: Si encontraste la solución a tu problema, puedes crear la respuesta y marcarla como valida. Para que quien tenga el mismo problema pueda encontrarlo facilmente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontre la solucion, al pareces es necesario tener el mismo orden de uso en el indice compuesto y en el codigo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor para que te respuesta sea mejor aceptada por la comunidad no uses imágenes y en su lugar edita y coloca el código como texto